# Is it OK to have one register API for mobile and web app in web API?

Tags: android, angular, webapi, createuser

I want to know when I'm writing a web API to make service  for mobile and angular 2 clients, should I write one register API for both of them (mobile and angular 2) or should I write for each one separately?
My register user view model for web and mobile are different.
I need some fields in web register user that I don't need in mobile.

Comment: it is perfectly fine. The API itself should be universal, for multiple client applications to call (webpage, mobile app view, etc.)

Comment: thanks for your answer but please read my edited question

Comment: Then make the fields you need for web *optional*. You can check if you are accessing the registration site over web or mobile and then display according to that.

Comment: it can be good idea. thanks